# Can Death Note be used to indirectly kill more than one person by killing the driver of a train/bus/plane?

Tags: death-note

If you state "Jack Hare" will die at precisely 15:00 12/03/14 without stating the location, and you write this without knowing where they will be at the time, and the person goes to work as per normal, can this be used to kill more than one person?

Comment: It's possible that the plane will crash, and all of the passengers would survive.

Answer (score 0):

[Rule X](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use:_X) states:

> 1. Suicide is a valid cause of death. Basically, all humans are thought to possess the possibility to commit suicide. It is, therefore, not something unbelievable to think of.
> 2. Whether the cause of the individual's death is either a suicide or accident, if the death leads to the death of more than the intended, the person will simply die of a heart attack. This is to ensure that other lives are not influenced.

[Rule XXVI](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use:_XXVI) states:

> 1. If you just write, "die of accident" for the cause of death, the victim will die from a natural accident after 6 minutes and 40 seconds from the time of writing it.
> 2. Even though only one name is written in the Death Note, if it influences and causes other humans that are not written in it to die, the victim's cause of death will be a heart attack.

It is clear that the Death Note cannot be used to indirectly kill other humans.

However, according to [Rule XLII](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use:_XLII) it is possible to shorten other lifespans.

> 1. The use of the Death Note in the human world sometimes affects other humans' lives or shortens their original life span, even though their names are not actually written in the Death Note itself. In these cases, no matter the cause, the god of death sees only the original lifespan and not the shortened lifespan.